# Regex to ensure that only 1 box is checked. It should fail if more than 1 is checked

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will ensure that only a single x is present within a multiline string.

For example. This would be good.

```
[x] Patch
[] Minor
[] Major
```

This should not match as more than 1 x is present

```
[x] Patch
[x] Minor
[] Major
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been banging my head against the wall on this one all day.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Please add its tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have newlines in the input, you'll need the DOTALL flag on. Use a negative look ahead for two of the target chars:

```
^(?s)(?!(.*\[x]){2}).*\[x]
```

See live demo [matching](https://rubular.com/r/a26NRsP2R5NoOY) and [not matching](https://rubular.com/r/V1PeYvVQcXXLSU)

I used `(?s)` to enable DOTALL, which for example works in java. Depending on your regex flavour and/or tool, you may need to use an option to enable DOTALL.

Comment: Thanks Bohemian. While this does work for most flavors it turns out I actually need it to work with ECMAScript (JavaScript). When I select ECMAScript it fails with a pattern error and shows this error "? The preceding token is not quantifiable"

Comment: Yup! You were right. I had to remove the (?s) for DOTALL and use the single flag (/s). That works for me now! Thank you!